# How can I change the behavior of a single method without re-implementing a large interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My situation is this:  I have a 3rd party library that exposes a method that takes an `HttpContextBase` object. However, I need to pass my context object *without* query params (the library can't be allowed to see them).  As luck would have it, there is already a wrapper class that does this, `HttpContextWrapper`. However, the constructor for `HttpContextWrapper` takes an `HttpContext`, and not an `HttpContextBase`.  I'm trying to avoid re-implementing the entirety of `HttpContextWrapper` (along with `HttpRequestWrapper`) just so I can make the property `Url` return a new query-free `Uri` object.  I could perhaps use reflection for ease, but I was hoping a better options exists.

Comment: Can You create a wrapper around the wrapper, that uses the `HttpContextBase`?

Comment: Copy your context object and clear/leave out all parameters in the copy before passing the copy to the lib?

Comment: I could make a wrapper around the wrapper, but I would need to pass the `HttpContextBase` to the contained `HttpContextWrapper`, which presents the same original problem (wrong type).  Copying the context object would work, but I don't know this won't cause problems; plus it seems a bit heavy-handed.